# Проблемы с TemplateBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

У меня есть расширение XAML `SomeExtension`, которое оформляется так:

```
<Rectangle Fill={SomeExtension <address of brush>}/>
```

Но когда я пытаюсь вместо `<address of brush>` подставить `{TemplateBinding Content}` (сам xaml-тэг `Rectangle` внутри `ControlTemplate`'а):

```
<Rectangle Fill={SomeExtension {TemplateBinding Content}}/>
```

то внутри кода расширения я получаю не контент, а объект типа `TemplateBindingExpression`. У него есть свойство `TemplateBindingExtension`, которое возвращает экземпляр одноимённого класса. У второго есть метод `ProvideValue`, и когда я его вызываю я опять получаю не контент, а `TemplateBindingExpression`. Замкнутый круг.

---

Что это за `TemplateBindingExpression`? Почему он так работает? Как мне взять и получить контент?

---

Код `ProvideValue` метода моего расширения:

```cs
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    var content = Content /*свойство*/ is TemplateBindingExtension /*expression до этого преобразованно в extension*/ binding ?
        binding.ProvideValue(provider) : Content;

        // прочая обработка
}
```

---

#### EDIT:

Я использую `SomeExtension` внутри стиля в 2-х местах:

1. `{SomeExtension MyBrush}`
2. `{SomeExtension {TemplateBinding Content}}` (вместо Content может быть любое другое свойство)

1-й случай работает корректно - возвращает кисть по адресу `MyBrush`. 2-й - нет. Вместо ожидаемой кисти по адресу, равному контенту, он возвращает какой-то `TemplateBindingExpression`, из которого значение контента получить нельзя, но очень хочется. Как это сделать?

Comment: Судя по тишине в комментариях, никто ничего не понял. Я тоже ничего не понял. Расскажите пожалуйста, какую вы задачу решаете. Вопрос выглядит как использование `TemplateBinding` не по назначению. Зачем здесь вообще нужен экстеншн?

Comment: @aepot Мне нужно использовать этот экстешн в 2-х местах:
1. `{SomeExtension MyBrush}`
2. `{SomeExtension {TemplateBinding Content}}` (вместо `Content` может быть любое другое свойство)
Я попытался усесться на 2-х стульях и думал, что во 2-м случае я сразу буду получать контент, но я получаю какое-то `TemplateBindingExpression`. Чё с ним делать - не понятно. Мне не хотелось менять архитектуру стиля (это использовалось в стиле) или страдать похожей ерундой. Я сам понимаю, что когда тут ты видишь код в 100 строк ты его не очень хочешь смотреть; сократил, и никто ничего не понял(

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, используйте редактирование. Добавьте код экстеншна в вопрос. Пока яснее не становится. Какую именно задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Может ли `IValueConverter` решить задачу? Вы знаете про конвертеры?

Comment: @aepot Конечно знаю, но как тогда внутри кода обратиться к свойству `Content` контрола, использующего мой стиль?

Comment: `{TemplateBinding Content}` возвращает экземпляр себя, так и должно быть. Потому что биндинг, это не просто указатель, а прокси-класс, который еще внутри себя вызывает событие при изменении свойства, для которого он инициализирован. Другими словами, в коде экстеншна вам надо научиться работать с биндингами, если уж вы решили делать именно так и не показывать, что это за мистический экстеншн, который так нужен, и который нельзя показывать. Но задача действительно странная.

Comment: Фу-у, что за не low-level'ный жаргон! Какие-то ассемблерные *указатели*. Выражайтесь языком богов - ссылки))))

Comment: Ваш юмор неуместен, хоть и понятен. Лучше расскажите, зачем втыкать прокладку в виде экстеншна между биндингом и свойством. И почему конвертер здесь не подходит. Я пытаюсь понять, как помочь вам.

Comment: Это нужно чтобы после применения стиля я, задав свойство `Content` (оно выбрано, потому что после применения стиля не отображается) я мог использовать нужные ресурсы. Например, у кнопки `Content` равно `AddButton` и мне нужно вместо единственного унылого текста отобразить и, например, иконку. Чтобы не писать дважды и более раз, что я хочу получить иконку именно для `AddButton` и текст именно для `AddButton`, и решил сделать это через экстешн (вам я показал, естественно упрощённый).

Comment: Контент из биндинга вы не получите никак по одной простой причине: он его не хранит.

Comment: Вот так понятнее, да. Иконку на основе контента получить можно с помощью конвертера. Он для этого и предназначен, собственно.

Comment: Так стиль "динамический" и зависит от свойства `Content`. Именно поэтому вся эта канитель, чтоб можно было все кнопки вот так под 1 стиль подстроить, только меняя свойство `Content`.

Comment: Можно через конвертер брать и создавать стиль во время runtime'а, но это выглядит как какое-то извращение.

Comment: Хотя я где-то слышал что чем-то подобным занимается react у веберов... Пока это выглядит как единственный выход

Comment: Так конвертер и будет вызываться биндингом каждый раз, когда контент меняется. Не вижу проблемы. Вы попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо за этот немного длинный, но интересный диалог программиста (или верстальщика)))))) и "бездаря" (где кто - решать вам). Пораскинув мозгами, думаю, ваше решение самое лучшее. Иду тестировать...

Comment: Есть еще мультибиндинг с мультиконвертером, в него можно засунуть не один контент, а кучу всего и переварить это вместе. Например помимо контента можно передать словарь со стилями, или еще с чем-нибудь, чтобы он мог пережевать все необходимые данные и выдать нужный результат. Это на случай, если просто контента для формирования результата недостаточно.